# How to take the string from input of argparse and use it as an object

Tags: python, object, command-line, argparse

I am trying to create a program that reads a string off an argparse input and uses that string to call a certain object and use that object for the rest of the function.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

class car:
    def __init__(self, color, year):
        self.color = color
        self.year = year

Beatle = car("blue", 1973)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--vehicleType")
args = parser.parse_args()

print("This "+args.vehicleType+ " is nice")
print("It was made:")
print(2018-args.vehicleType.year)
print("years ago")
```

However, I keep getting back this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(2018-args.vehicleType.year)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

I think the program is reading args.vehicleType as a string, while I want to read it in as an object. How do I get around this?
-Cheers, and thanks in advance! ~O. Fried

Comment: Yes, `args.vehicleType` is a string.  It's the responsibility of your own code to map strings like that on to objects like `Beatle`. The variable name `Beatle` references a `car` object.  The string 'Beattle' does not reference that.

Comment: how would you map strings onto objects?

Comment: With a dictionary.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: Do you understand dictionaries?  Argparse just tells you what the user wants.  It's up to you do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to actually create the object after? Something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
class car:
    def __init__(self, color, year, type):
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.type = type

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--vehicleType") # Accept the argument as vehicle type.
args = parser.parse_args()

Beatle = car("blue", 1973, str(args.vehicleType)) # Now create the object.

print("This " + Beatle.type+ " is nice") # Use it here.
print("It was made:")
print(2018-Beatle.year) # And here.
print("years ago.")
```

Comment: yes this seems useful, thanks! can you just explain what dest is though? I really dont understand...

Comment: wait I don't think so. Because if I added another instance of the class vehicle I would need to change the data inside it-meaning it couldnt be "blue" and 1973 for all of them

Comment: I'm sorry, you actually do not need dest. FYI: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#dest

Comment: wait I don't think so. Because if I added another instance of the class vehicle I would need to change the data inside it-meaning it couldnt be "blue" and 1973 for all of them

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand that comment. What are you particularly trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary of cars

```
adict = {'beattle': car('blue',1973), 'ford': car('black', 1907),...}

yourcar = adict[args.vehicleType]
print(yourcar.year)
```